# Why to do transpose this way instead of that way?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, transpose

An intuitive and "standard" way to do transpose on square matrix is this (assume zero based indices):

```
for i = 0 to N-2
    for j = i+1 to N-1
        swap A(i,j) with A(j,i)
```

However, other day I noticed another way to do transpose and I'm wondering why author went extra length to do it in this particular way:

```
for j = 1 to N-1
    for i = 0 to j-1
        swap A(i,j) with A(j,i)
```

First approach is what I did myself and later also found in Wikipedia. The reference to 2nd approach is very thin, the only one I can find is in the CLRS book but on an unrelated topic. My first thought was that it might reduce cache misses but that can't be true because we are doing swaps so cache miss is going to be same. Number of iterations also seems to be same.

So the question is why someone would take the trouble of reversing the loop order from traditional approach?

Comment: [Tomayto, tomahto](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomayto,_tomahto). There's no difference.